# excel VBA using Range() and ActiveCell.Offset()

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using excel VBA and I'm trying to increment a Range selection in a loop.

```
Sub sorter()
Dim i As Integer
Dim copyLoc As String = "E1"

For i = 0 To 5
Range(copyLoc).Select '//what type is Range() supposed to take?
Selection.Copy
copyLoc = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) '//what type does ActiveCell.Offset return?
Next i
End Sub
```

I'm sure the problem is with the data type that ActiveCell.Offset is returning. Can anyone tell me what I should use instead? Thanks kindly!

Comment: `Dim CopyLoc as Range` and `Set CopyLoc = Sheet1.Range("E1")` is probably what you are looking for. Instead of `Select` and `activate`, just `Set CopyLoc = CopyLoc.Offset(0,6)` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above. "Range" is an object type. So you want to dim your variable as a "Range" not a string:

```
Sub sorter()
Dim i As Integer
Dim copyLoc As Range

Set copyloc = Range("E1")

For i = 0 To 5
    'copy from copyloc and stick it in a cell offset 6 columns to the right
    copyLoc.Copy Destination:=copyLoc.Offset(0,6)     

    'Increment to the next row?
    Set copyLoc = copyLoc.Offset(1)
Next i
End Sub
```

I'm just guessing here at what you are trying to accomplish, but either way I think this will get you in the ballpark. If you are incrementing through 6 rows starting at E1 you could also use something like:

```
Sub sorter()
    Dim rngRow as Range
    Dim copyRange as Range

    Set copyRange = Range("E1:E6")

    'Loop through each row in the range's "Rows" collection
    For each rngRow in copyRange.Rows
         'Copy the value from the "E" column to the "K" column in this row
         rngRow.Cells(1,11).value = rngRow.cells(1,5).value
    Next rngRow
End Sub
```

Being able to loop/iterate through each item in a collection, and understanding that most objects in VBA are part of a collection is hugely powerful.

For instance, looping through all of the sheets in the ThisWorkbook.Worksheets collection:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    'print the name of the worksheet to the "immediate" pane
    debug.print ws.name
Next ws
```

Or looping through all cells in a range's "Cells" collection:

```
Dim rngCell as Range
For each rngCell in Range("A1:C50").cells
    'do something to the cell
Next rngCell
```